# Paypal url link

Tags: php, paypal

I've a custom php code with paypal.

I want you use this method:

```
header("location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=mymail@maymail.com&cmd=_xclick&currency_code=EUR&item_name=NAIL2016&amount=50");
```

I can use use a variable for the amount field ?

Like this: `amount=$mytotal` (don't work)

Thanks

Comment: There's no reason why that shouldn't work, as long as `$mytotal` contains a valid numerical value and your string is enclosed in double quotes ("like this", 'not like this'). But you really should be using encrypted buttons because there's nothing to stop a user from editing the URL and changing `amount` to some other value.

Comment: A programmer will never say "it doesn't work", a programmer will mention the error that is being thrown or explain the actual result versus expected result.

Comment: Put whole string you're passing to the `header` function into a variable and `var_dump` that variable to see, how does it look. Or `var_dump` directly the `$mytotal` variable to see it's value. Or the best (and only proper) solution would be to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set variable value first, like this:

```
$mytotal = 50;
```

Then you can call header function with this variable:

```
header("location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?business=mymail@maymail.com&cmd=_xclick&currency_code=EUR&item_name=NAIL2016&amount=$myTotal");
```

Works for me.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help you out :)

Answer (score 0):

Helps to make your code more understandable...

```php
$mytotal = 50;
$url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
$param = [ // or array( in older PHP 
     "business=mymail@maymail.com", 
     "cmd=_xclick", 
     "currency_code=EUR",
     "item_name=NAIL2016",
     "amount=$mytotal"
];
header("location: $url?". join( '&', $param));
```

Or you could make $param an associative array and use `http_build_query` instead of join...

```
$param = [ // or array( in older PHP 
     'business' => 'mymail@maymail.com', 
     'cmd' => '_xclick', 
     'currency_code' => 'EUR',
     'item_name' => 'NAIL2016',
     'amount' => "$mytotal"
];
header("location: $url?". http_build_query( $param));
```